# ios - What's wrong with my custom @synchronize setter \ getter?

Tags: ios, properties

This is the properties declaration:

```
@property (atomic, weak) zooView* zooView;
```

This is my custom implementation:

```
__weak zooView* _zooView;

-(zooView*) getZooView
{
    return _zooView;
}

-(void) setZooView:(btBasePinView*)inZooView
{
    _zooView = inZooView;
}
```

I am accessing this property on another thread, on the same class:

```
[self.zooView imgLoadComplete:self.fullImg];
```

From some reason, when I access self.zooView I am returned with a nil object.
If I remove the custom setter \ getter, everything works fine.

What might be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using global variables here? Seems like a bad idea

Comment: Yeah, as a guess, a second object is overwriting what every value you set. It looks like a instance method, but it will behave like a class method. The default implementation will keep each instance separate.

Comment: what other variable should I be using?

Comment: how do I keep the instances separate? Could you perhaps supply a sample code to demonstrate the difference? I am sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: Could be because you specify atomic in the property declaration, but your custom implementation doesn't deal with any atomicity, so whatever you have going on in the other thread might require it to in fact be an atomic action.

Comment: mm atomic here doesn't have much input, when I change the default declaration to nonatomic it works the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter for zooView should be -zooView not -getZooView.

To have an instance variable instead of a global, just synthesize it.

```
@synthesize zooView = _zooView;

-(zooView*) zooView
{
    return _zooView;
}

-(void) setZooView:(btBasePinView*)inZooView
{
    _zooView = inZooView;
}
```

This will define an ivar _zooView with your specified getter/setter.